# View estimated size of GitHub repository before cloning

Tags: github

I want to view the total repo size of a project hosted on GitHub without having to clone it. Sometimes I do this:

1. Start cloning some GitHub repository

   > Receiving objects:  45% (218/476), 5.50 MiB | 27 KiB/s

   Already drained 5MB? Suspend...

   ```
   ^Z
   ```
2. Clone the repository on a server with a normal internet connection *just* to see its size.
3. Continue (or abort) the local cloning.

How do I find out the repository size in advance? In the search I see repository size, but not in other places.

Comment: Check the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8646517/198836).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Github API:

```
$ echo https://github.com/hlamer/enki.git | perl -ne 'print $1 if m!([^/]+/[^/]+?)(?:\.git)?$!' | xargs -i curl -s -k https://api.github.com/repos/'{}' | grep size
"size": 284,
```

Comment: On mac, there's no `-i` parameter for `xargs`, so it's: `$ echo https://github.com/hlamer/enki.git | perl -ne 'print $1 if m!([^/]+/[^/]+?)(?:\.git)?$!' | xargs -I{} curl -s -k https://api.github.com/repos/'{}' | grep size`

Comment: and that is size in... kilobytes?

Answer (score 8):

In Firefox you can use the [GitHub Repository Size](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-repo-size/) add-on.

[image: github info bar]

Comment: Why the downvote? Does the extension or userscript fails to work or contains malware?

Comment: No, everything works just fine...

Comment: also it's opensource, so you can review the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Chrome browser and install this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-repository-size/apnjnioapinblneaedefcnopcjepgkci/related?ref=producthunt)

Adds the repo size to the home page:

[image: GitHub Repo Size extension screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

One can achieve this using one's browser console and running

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/[USERNAME]/[REPO]')
  .then(v => v.json()).then((function(v){
   console.log(v['size'] + "KB")
  })
)
```

Let's consider a practical example.

Assuming one wants to find the size of [this repo](https://github.com/goncaloperes/TimeSeries) using Firefox.

Open the console with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`.

Then paste the following code

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/goncaloperes/TimeSeries')
  .then(v => v.json()).then((function(v){
   console.log(v['size'] + "KB")
  })
)
```

Press enter and one will receive the size of the repo as one can see in the image bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
curl \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
-s https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux | \
jq '.size' | \
numfmt --to=iec --from-unit=1024
```

**Explanation:**

1. fetch repo info from [github api](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository) using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

We get a json response like this:

```
{
  "id": 2325298,
  "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzI1Mjk4",
  "name": "linux",
  "full_name": "torvalds/linux",
  "private": false,
     ...
  "size": 3018913,  <<<This is what we need
  "stargazers_count": 99224,
  "watchers_count": 99224,
     ...
}
```

2. Pipe the json response to [jq parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and find the required attribute-value pair.

   `.` indicates the root of the json body and `size` is the required attribute from the root body

Output (the size in kB):

```
3018913
```

3. Then pipe the output to [numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html)

```
$ man numfmt

--to=[UNIT]
     iec    1K = 1024, 1M = 1048576, ...

--from-unit=N
     specify the input unit size (instead of the default 1)
     (it basically tells that the input is in kB(1024B) insted of B
```

Output:

```
2.9G
```

For private repos pass a token as a header

```
-H "Authorization: token GITHUB_TOKEN"
```

replace GITHUB_TOKEN with a [github token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) that has access to private repos

https://command-not-found.com/jq

https://command-not-found.com/numfmt

Comment: Can you explain what this command does? How does it help in this situation? Thanks

Comment: It fetches repository metadata using `curl`, then extracts "size" field from it using `jq`, then  converts raw bytes to human-readable filesize with `numfmt`.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Mac users

The following [one-liner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39587/view-estimated-size-of-github-repository-before-cloning#comment70045_39642) should do the trick:

```
echo https://github.com/andreikop/enki.git | perl -ne 'print $1 if m!([^/]+/[^/]+?)(?:\.git)?$!' | xargs -I{} curl -s -k https://api.github.com/repos/'{}' | grep size
# "size": 17039
```