# View estimated size of GitLab repository before cloning

Tags: github, gitlab

I would like to view the total repository size of a project hosted on GitLab without having to clone it.

I was able to find one for GitHub [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39587/view-estimated-size-of-github-repository-before-cloning), but I can't figure out how to do it on GitLab.

The GitHub example:

```
$ echo https://github.com/hlamer/enki.git | perl -ne 'print $1 if m! 
([^/]+/[^/]+?)(?:\.git)?$!' | xargs -i curl -s -k 
https://api.github.com/repos/'{}' | grep size


 >>"size": 284,
```

Answer (score 0):

GitLab UI may have changed since the original question, but it looks like the size is displayed at the top of the web UI main screen for the repo.

For example, I have a repo that looks like this:

```
                                <PROJECTNAME>
                                project id 26867

3 Commits  1 Branch 0 Tags **8.5 GB Project Storage**
```